# How do i change the font size with still the same font in Swiftui

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

iam trying to change the font size of an Textlabel so that i still have the same font. Every option i tried also changed the font to the basic one, but i want to use Headline or make the Text fat.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var fontSize: CGFloat = 16
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello, world!")
                .font(.system(size: fontSize))
            .padding()
            
            Button("Change font") {
                fontSize += 2
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This increases the font size if you click the button. You can, of course, use all kinds of methods to change the fontSize property.

It's not a headline any more, but that is, as far as I understand the apple documentation, a specific font size and font weight for the system font. You can always try the different kind of font weights to mimic the headline thickness.

Comment: i know about font(.system(size: fontSize)) but when iam trying to change the size that way it always change to the basic font but i want it be .headline :/

Comment: But isn't that a bit odd? You choose .headline, because you want it to have a defined size and weight specified by the standard TextStyle. If you want to change the font size dynamically, you need to make a specific font.

Comment: Ok thank you, i like the thickness from headline, thats because i asked

Comment: I updated the answer. I'm sorry that I can't help you further. Just play around with the font weight to mimic the headline with different font sizes. Good lick.